# compare number of items in the mysql row (php wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress mockup, I have meta_value for users which is called ref_credit. This meta value for sandro looks like this:

```
174 1   ref_credit  a:2:{i:0;s:1:"9";i:1;s:2:"10";}
```

Means he referred users with id=9,10

Another user meta_value looks like this:

```
209 9   ref_credit  a:1:{i:0;s:2:"11";}
```

He referred only 1 user id=11.

Now I'd like to create a simple leader-board, I mocked up something but logics is completely wrong. I understand my code compares values and orders by this. I want to order it by number of users referred.

Any ideas?

complete function is this:

```
    //get_users calls WP_User_Query and returns an array of matching users
    $users = get_users(

        array(  'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
                'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'ref_credit', // the meta field (or key) we want to target
                                              'compare' => '>='  // comparison method (optional:  =, >, <, etc)
        )))
    );

            //custom function for comparing the data we want to sort by
            function cmp($a, $b){
              if ($a->points == $b->points) {
                return 0;
              }
              return ($a->points > $b->points) ? -1 : 1;
            }

    //usort sorts our $users array with our function cmp()
    usort($users, 'cmp');

    //leaving an array of $users sorted by the value of meta 'points'
    echo '<ol>';
        foreach ($users as $user) {  
            echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ol>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few problems.

The first is that `all_with_meta` doesn't seem to bring back the metadata, despite what the name implies.  Not sure what it's supposed to do - the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users#Parameters) doesn't help much.  So you'll have to grab the `ref_credit` values yourself.

Secondly, your comparison seems to be using something called `points`, not `ref_credit`.  Not sure where that's coming from.  Since `ref_credit` is an array, you'll have to compare the array lengths, not the values themselves (using `count` say).

Leaving your original query as is, something like this should work (though you may have to check I've got the `cmp` result the right way around):

```
//get_users calls WP_User_Query and returns an array of matching users
$users = get_users(
    array(  'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array( 'key' => 'ref_credit', // the meta field (or key) we want to target
                    'compare' => '>='  // comparison method (optional:  =, >, <, etc)
                )
            )
        )
);

foreach($users as $user_id => $user) {
    $user->ref_credit = get_user_meta($user_id, 'ref_credit', true);
}

//custom function for comparing the data we want to sort by
function cmp($a, $b){
    return count($b->ref_credit) - count($a->ref_credit);
}

usort($users, 'cmp');

//leaving an array of $users sorted by the value of meta 'points'
echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
    }
echo '</ol>';
```